# Packet with Strict Source Route IP Option not being sent

Tags: sockets, routes, ip, checksum

I am trying to send a UDP packet that uses strict source routing (IP Option 9).

The SSR option is added using setsockopt(), and looks fine from within Wireshark, however the UDP checksum is incorrect - always out by 4.
The Wireshark warning says this may be caused by checksum offloading, however verifying with ethtool, my NIC does not have tx-checksumming enabled (and apparently does not support this).

The packet is still sent, and received by the first node in the route, however no subsequent packets are sent on to the next node in the route.

ip_forwarding and accept_source_route are enabled within sysctl on nodes.

Am I missing something?

Any comments appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that accept_source_route=1 was not set in sysctl. Instead, deny_source_route=0 was set - this was the default setting in Raspbian Jessie Lite.